# Is possible to not mount a component everytime is rendered by a father component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

In `Father` component I render `Child` component that is a form with states inside. When I render `Father` i don't want to mount `Child` component and reset it's states. It is possible?

I tried rendering `Child` component using `useMemo` hook, but it mounts the component everytime the hook returns it.

```js
const Father = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(null);

    const renderForm = useMemo(() => {
        return (
            <Child
                setDefaultFormData={(value) => setFormData(value)}
            >
            </Child>
        );
    }, [formData]);

    return (
        <>
            <div>{renderForm}</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Father;
```

Any help out there? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the code you showed would re-mount the child. Even without the useMemo, it shouldn't re-mount. Here's my attempt to reproduce what you're describing, and it only ever mounts once: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-lzk7t7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Updated my sandbox. It had strict mode enabled which was confusing things. Now it just goes through a sequence of: "Father rendering" -> "Child rendering" -> "child has mounted" -> "setting state to cause a rerender" -> "Father rendering" -> "Child rendering"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you added formData to the *useMemo* dependency list.
You are updating *formData* based on the previous state, and *formData* is not needed in the dependency list.
Try this:

```
  const renderForm = useMemo(() => {
        return (
            <Child
                setDefaultFormData={(value) => setFormData(value)}
            >
            </Child>
        );
    }, []);
```

*useMemo* works as expected in this case, it only updates when some dependencies in the dependency list have been updated.

Comment: I added `formData` to useMemo dependency array because I want to update the Child only when a state of the Child changes, I pass the value with `setDefaultFormData` to the father. Still not working.

Comment: Look at the example https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-tree-s7qgew?file=/src/App.js, it works as expected

Comment: @DmitiyZhiganov yes I checked. But I don't know why in my code don't work. I'm preparing a codeSandbox to share it and see if you see something that I don't.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code `setDefaultFormData={(value) => setFormData(value)}` leads to the creation of a new function every time the parent renders which causes the `Child` component to re-render because `prevProps.setDefaultFormData` != `nextProps.setDefaultFormData`, beside that React by default re-renders all children when parent component renders, so you have to wrap your child component with `React.memo()` and pass `setFormData` directly `setDefaultFormData={setFormData}` and use it normally

[image: Edit brave-chatelet-qvkv04]